# How can I change a value of an NSObject at a keypath?

Tags: ios, nsobject

I have an NSObject with my profile information on it. An array with my favorite colours and favorite numbers, and a string with the name of my best friend.

```
{
favoriteColors =     (
    Green,
    Blue,
    Orange
);
favoriteNumbers =     (
    3,
    16,
    20
);
bestFriend = Josh;
}
```

Now, I want to update my profile information and replace my bestFriend to be "Alex".

I'm looking for a function that would do this:

```
[profileInformation replaceAtKeyPath:@"bestFriend" with: @"Alex"];
```

Many things I try give errors saying "Expression is not assignable", such as

```
[profileInformation valueForKeyPath:@"bestFriend"] = @"Alex";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called KVC (NSKeyValueCoding)

```
[profileInformation setValue:@"Alex" forKey:@"bestFriend"]
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValue:forKeyPath:

Also note that NSKeyValueCoding is an informal protocol, which means that all NSObjects automatically conform to it.  This is why Xcode autocomplete will allow you to call `-setValue:forKey:` on any Objective-C Foundation object